# Python: problem after I have installed mgwr

Tags: python, geopandas

I have installed a package called [mgwr](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mgwr) trough `anaconda`. After the installation `geopandas` gives problems that was not giving before the installation of `mgwr`.

```
      5 import pandas as pd
      6 import seaborn as sns
----> 7 import geopandas as gpd
      8 import mgwr
      9 from mgwr.gwr import GWR

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
      6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in <module>
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 import fiona
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import six

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py in <module>
     81     os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + ";" + libdir
     82 
---> 83 from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
     84 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
     85 from fiona.env import ensure_env_with_credentials, Env

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/collection.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat, vfs
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import buffer_to_virtual_file, remove_virtual_file, GEOMETRY_TYPES

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.78.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpoppler.78.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

I am now trying to install trough `conda-forge`

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: I think this is related to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881148/python-problem-to-import-fiona-after-other-installation). You have to install all packages (if possible) from conda-forge to ensure that all dependencies work together. Details here https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: @martinfleis should I unistall all the packages i installed trough `anaconda`?

Comment: Just reinstall them using conda-forge in a strict mode -  `conda config --add channels conda-forge` `conda config --set channel_priority strict`. That should do the trick. Then you can reinstall your packages and in `conda list` you can check their source. It should be conda-forge, not pkgs.

Comment: @martinfleis I tried but I get the message that `# All requested packages already installed.
`

Comment: Then you can either remove them and install them again from conda-forge or try it from scratch in new environment. `conda create --name my_env`