# Python: problem to import fiona after other installation

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I don't why but I am now experiencing this issue on mac. I installed everything trough `anaconda`. Everything was working fine before a `Restart` of the system

```
import fiona

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4c762272c079> in <module>
----> 1 import fiona

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py in <module>
     81     os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + ";" + libdir
     82 
---> 83 from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
     84 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
     85 from fiona.env import ensure_env_with_credentials, Env

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/collection.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat, vfs
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import buffer_to_virtual_file, remove_virtual_file, GEOMETRY_TYPES

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.76.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Did you install everything from conda-forge?

Comment: no, I installed a package called `mgwr` trough `conda-forge`. Before I installed everything trough `anaconda` software

Comment: conda-forge is a channel from which the `conda` program downloads packages. try this again in as fresh environment `conda create --name=gis python=3.7 fiona geopandas --channel=conda-forge`